# Keyframe css animation

Tags: html, css

### Question

let's if i have the following example

```
A-------------B------------C
```

how i can start an animation from the middle ( `B` ) then it go to `A` then to `B` and finaly it go to `C` , i made an example but it's not working good.

### Code

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}
.container .line {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.line:after{
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  25%{
    left: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    left: 400px;
  }
}
.line:after {
  -webkit-animation: move 1s alternate infinite;
  -moz-animation: move 1s alternate infinite;
  -ms-animation: move 1s alternate infinite;
  -o-animation: move 1s alternate infinite;
  animation: move 1s alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it this way, I thinks it's working well.

In stead of `alternate` I did use `linear`. It makes the animation smoother.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}
.container .line {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.line:after{
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  25%{
    left: 0px;
  }
  75%{
    left: 400px;
  }
  100%{
    left: 200px;
  }
}
.line:after {
  -webkit-animation: move linear 1s infinite;
  -moz-animation: move linear 1s infinite;
  -ms-animation: move linear 1s infinite;
  -o-animation: move linear 1s infinite;
  animation: move linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this, also if add `linear` (because default is `ease`) you will get something like this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/270/)

```css
.container .line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.line:after{
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  animation: move 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {left: 200px;}
  25%{left: 0px;}
  50% {left: 200px;}
  75% {left: 400px;}
  100%{left: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```